Separating Messages in Admin-Client Chat Using SignalR in .NET Core 6 with Angular
I'm implementing an admin-client chat option on my website using SignalR with .NET Core 6 and Angular. Here's what I have so far:
When a user wants to register a complaint, they press the chat button, creating a group in SignalR. This group is then displayed to admins. When an admin clicks join on a listing, they are added to that group (each group consists of only two people). However, when an admin joins multiple clients, the messages sent in each group get mixed up.
For example:
[
    {"user":"Admin","message":"hellooo"},
    {"user":"ramanna","message":"hui"},
    {"user":"Admin","message":"ff"},
    {"user":"rai","message":"nee"},
    {"user":"ramanna","message":"ttt"},
    {"user":"rai","message":"nn"},
    {"user":"ramanna","message":"ttt"},
    {"user":"rai","message":"yyyyy"}
]

When we change the user in the admin panel, sent (from admin) and received (selected user) messages should be displayed.
What is the best way to separate the messages properly?

It sounds like there's a logical error in the method you send messages in the hub, and some of the code in your Angular that accepts messages  also needs to be checked.
